# Can you run Fortnite on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wine

Can you run [Fortnite](https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en-US/home) on Ubuntu 16.04. When I use Wine 3.1 it pauses when it downloads.
Is there any way to run it?

Fortnite is a co-op sandbox survival game developed by Epic Games and People Can Fly, with the former publishing it. The game was released as a paid-for early access title for Microsoft Windows, macOS, PlayStation 4 and Xbox One on July 25, 2017, with a full free-to-play release expected in 2018.

Comment: What is Fortnite, where do you download it from, what does the site say about Ubuntu support ? Please update your question with any relevant information !!

Comment: It appears to only be available for Windows and Mac, so you probably can't run it on Ubuntu without a VM.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have seen no recent news of Fortnite being ported to Ubuntu...

Comment: Isn't it a bit weird they ignore Linux users altogether? Any idea why they give up on such a growing market?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The anti-cheat system will not allow you to play over wine or PlayOnLinux.
But you can run a KVM+QEMU high-efficiency virtual machine with Windows installed that should let you play with good performance.

Comment: Please can you you how to make a vm with 25G in qemu/kvm.                                  When I use Vmware-Player it says "unsupported driver" because Vmware-player emulates that.

Comment: @JohnOlar There are tutorials around the internet, and also [here in AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=kvm+qemu). If you want further information, you should mark this as an answer and ask specifically for that.

Answer (score 3):

As of today, you can only play Save the World (PvE) in Wine. You can use [Lutris](https://lutris.net/) to install it easily. To install Lutris, open the Terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and enter (copy and paste, followed by ENTER, each line one by one), the following commands:

```
ver=$(lsb_release -sr); if [ $ver != "18.04" -a $ver != "17.10" -a $ver != "17.04" -a $ver != "16.04" ]; then ver=18.04; fi

echo "deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_$ver/ ./" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris.list

(enter your password)

wget -q http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_$ver/Release.key -O- | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt update

sudo apt install -y lutris
```

Then visit [this page](https://lutris.net/games/fortnite/) and click on "Install".

To play Battle Royale (PvP) you need to use Windows, either in a [virtual machine with its own graphics card](http://vfio.blogspot.it/2015/05/vfio-gpu-how-to-series-part-4-our-first.html) or in a dual-boot setup, due to the anti-cheat not currently working in Wine.

Answer (score -1):

Though I like some of the answers they both were given with assumptions that it's not going to work, so here's an answer I found from a reddit winehq maintainer of Fortnite support on Wine;

https://www.reddit.com/r/FORTnITE/comments/6rtlki/fortnite_on_linux_it_works/

Comment: No it does not. Your link is old and no longer correct.